# onchange_callback does fire on blur (or at all) in tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have the following code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    onchange_callback: function (editor) {
        alert("onchange_callback");
    }
});
```

No matter what I try, the `onchange_callback` will not fire. I'm using the 4.2 version and have also tested this with the 4.1 version as well.

Comment: [doc](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onChange)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, since I'm using 4.x it would be http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.change. However, are you suggesting that `onchange_callback` isn't the correct thing to use, even though it is in the documentation and claims to be what I'm trying to us it for?

Comment: Ah yes I fubared the link, sorry. Yes, when searching for `tinymce onchange_callback` this is what came back; The [`onchange_callback`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:onchange_callback) seems to be only in v3, [not in v4](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:onchange_callback).

Comment: Thank you Kenny. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the `onchange_callback` is not available in version 4.x of TinyMCE.

Instead, [this can be used](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.change) to be notified that the contents of the editor has changed:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('change', function(e) {
            console.log('change event', e);
        });
    }
});
```